# How to have separate layout sets per screen in XMonad?

Tags: layout, xmonad

The use case is basically to have layouts with a master area on the left side for my right monitor, and the same layouts only 'reflected horizontally' (using Layout.Reflect) on my left monitor, so that the master areas are always in the center.
A solution that has separate layout sets per screen should be more than enough for this.

I have a vague memory of finding such a module way back when,
but I've went through the entirety of xmonad-contrib recently (looked at xmonad-extras as well) and didn't find a solution for this.

There are separate layouts per workspace, and having separate workspaces per screen, but I want to switch between screens on the fly and have consistent layouts as described above.

In case I'm not missing any module in contrib, could someone please point me in a good starting direction as to how to implement such a thing?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate. will close. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but you can define a number of layouts, and then use Alt+space to cycle between them. That way you can have different layouts on different screens.

For example, I like to toggle between the `Full` and `ResizableTall` layouts:

```
myLayouts = ResizableTall nmaster delta ratio [] ||| Full
  where
     -- The default number of windows in the master pane
     nmaster = 1

     -- Default proportion of screen occupied by master pane
     ratio   = 1/2

     -- Percent of screen to increment by when resizing panes
     delta   = 3/100
```

If you're looking for a way to have different workspaces default to different layouts, I don't know how to do that within XMonad.

Comment: Yes I already have multiple layouts I cycle with. What I want is for the sets of layout I cycle through to be different depending on which monitor I am on. I know a module in xmoad-contrib that can have different workspaces use different layouts, but that doesn't help me, as those workouts can appear on either of my screens in real life use. Thanks for trying though!